# How to mute ads?

Tags: audio, video, ads, silent-mode, mute

Even when the phone is on silent mode, some apps show audible video ads.

How can I mute such ads?

Comment: Well, I've never seen this happening... If I put my phone in DND (Do not Disturb), only alarms will have sound... How are you putting it to silent mode?

Comment: Yes, I set it to the (Do not Disturb) mode. Maybe the ad audio plays on media channel

Comment: @Abdulrahman yes you definitely have to put media on silent, putting ringtone on silent won't help in this case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Video ads use Android media stream to play sound

Muting the phone media mutes ads as well

Answer (score 0):

Get "Sound Assistant" or other apps that can manage sound settings "per app" (as it's for Samsung and I'm not sure it will be compatible with other brands).

Find Google Play Movies or whatever it's named in your language. Mute this app.